# How to commit and push in visual studio code with internal terminal to Team Foundation server

Tags: tfs

How to commit and push in visual studio code with internal terminal to Team Foundation server. We should able to commit from Terminal of visual studio code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to commit through Internal terminal of Visual studio code.
* git commit -a
After this command it ask for commit message, then enter your message in save it. 
Once you are out of saving your commit message push the code.

- git push origin master

You can see your committed message in TFS history